# Joining two dataframes with non unique column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**Synopsys**

I already have a solution using "for" loop but I was wondering if there are elegant ways, possibly using *dplyr* or base R.

**Existing Data**

2 data frames. Both have the exact number of **non unique** markers in the exact order; except eeg has unpredictable number of zeros. The behavioural data set "behav" has the stimulus number "stim" associated with marker. (actually I have more columns in each dataframe but not included them for simplicity)

```
behav = data.frame(
  marker = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,7,13),
  stim   = c(168,168,168,78,78,78,23,55)
)

eeg = data.frame(
  marker = c(0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,7,0,13)
)
```

**Requirement**

I need to label eeg data with stimulus numbers from the behav. Preservation of **row order** is a must have.

The result should looks like this:

```
eeg2 = data.frame(
  marker = c(0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,7,0,13),
  stim   = c(0,0,168,0,0,168,0,0,168,0,0,78,0,0,78,0,0,78,0,23,0,55)
)
```

**My solution**

This does the job and performance is not bad for a large eeg dataset.

```
eeg2=eeg;
eeg2$stim=NA;

lrow=1;
for(i in 1:nrow(behav)){
  behav_marker = behav[i, "marker"];

  for(j in lrow:nrow(eeg)){
    eeg_marker = eeg[j, "marker"];
    if(eeg_marker == behav_marker){
      eeg2[j,'stim'] = behav[i,'stim'];
      lrow = j+1;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Question**
Can my solution be improved with more elegant way using *dplyr* or base R functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem only comes from the rows with zeros but the rest is the same in the exact same order, you can solve your problem by defining the `stim` column as only zeros, then filling the rows with a non-zero value for `marker` with the corresponding value of `behav`:

```
eeg$stim <- 0
eeg$stim[eeg$marker!=0] <- behav$stim

eeg
   # marker stim
# 1       0    0
# 2       0    0
# 3       1  168
# 4       0    0
# 5       0    0
# 6       2  168
# 7       0    0
# 8       0    0
# 9       3  168
# 10      0    0
# 11      0    0
# 12      1   78
# 13      0    0
# 14      0    0
# 15      2   78
# 16      0    0
# 17      0    0
# 18      3   78
# 19      0    0
# 20      7   23
# 21      0    0
# 22     13   55
```

Comment: thank you Cath. You made it so easy, was banging my head for days :-)

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution has already been provided by for completeness sake here is how I'd approach using `dplyr`:

Use `dplyr::left_join()` to merge `eeg` and `behav` and then fill the `NA`s with 0 with `dplyr::mutate()`:

```
eeg2 <- dplyr::left_join(eeg, behav, by = c("marker"))

eeg2 <- dplyr::mutate(eeg2, stim = dplyr::if_else(is.na(stim), 0, stim))
```

Result:

```
   marker stim
1       0    0
2       0    0
3       1  168
4       1   78
5       0    0
6       0    0
7       2  168
8       2   78
9       0    0
10      0    0
11      3  168
12      3   78
13      0    0
14      0    0
15      1  168
16      1   78
17      0    0
18      0    0
19      2  168
20      2   78
21      0    0
22      0    0
23      3  168
24      3   78
25      0    0
26      7   23
27      0    0
28     13   55
```

In this particular instance though, I'd recommend the use of pipes (`%>%`) from `magrittr` (it adds a bit of overhead but makes the code a bit shorter and it flows better:

```
eeg2 <- dplyr::left_join(eeg, behav, by = c("marker")) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(stim = dplyr::if_else(is.na(stim), 0, stim))
```